# Can someone recognize this FPS from a sceenshot?

Tags: game-identification, first-person-shooter

Saw this game as a screenshot on a laptop add-on screen website. Seems like a nice first person shooter but I have no idea what game it is. Anyone? Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Quick tip: Right click and click the "Search the web for image" option in the future! might save u time

Comment: @Penguin out of curiosity, which browser has such feature? I am using latest firefox, and there is no such option.

Comment: I was wondering how you'd recognise Frames Per Second from a screenshot (a still image). Then I saw what you meant!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Chrome (maybe chromium). You can also use image search in images.google.com.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari oh sorry assumed it was standard, Im using Edge but im pretty sure any Chromium browsrt has it like qwr said

Comment: @qwr no, Chromium v90 doesn't have this menu item. I suppose it's Chrome-specific feature.

Comment: If you don't have the option in your browser, you can go to https://images.google.com/ to search from an image

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This game is [valorant](/questions/tagged/valorant). You can see Viper in the middle-right of the screen.

Comment: Similar to CS:GO.

Answer (score 18):

I searched Google for the image and one of the results was [this page](https://www.egames.news/entretenimiento/Valorant-Como-mejorar-tu-apuntado-y-precision-al-disparar-20210307-0033.html). You can see that it's the same image, and the game is "**Valorant**".

Comment: Or just open images.google.com on any browser.